# (sur/in)-jectivity

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm having trouble showing this:

Let $T : V → W$ be a linear map of finite dimensional vector spaces. Prove that $T$ is surjective (respectively, injective) if and only if $T^*$ is injective (respectively, surjective).

I've been using the dimension theorem to show relatedness through cardinality, but this has unearthed nothing. I was thinking that a method using canonical isomorphisms might be in order. I suspect the answer is just an $iff$-chain of theorems.

Just as an aside, is there an "induces" arrow?

Comment: Do you mean $\Leftrightarrow$? That's `$\Leftrightarrow$`. There's also `$\Leftarrow$` and `$\Rightarrow$`, and if you like them longer, there's $\Longleftrightarrow$, which is `$\Longleftrightarrow$`, for example.

Comment: No, totally not related to this question. Just something I write a lot in other areas of mathematics.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a context in which it comes up?

Comment: You may find that someone quickly writes you a complete answer to this particular question. However, in general, with questions like this it is best to tell us exactly where you are getting stuck, what you have tried, try to quantify what your difficulty is, etc... this can help us give you better answers.

Comment: Dear Barisa, Try proving first that if $T$ is surjective then $T^*$ is injective.  This follows essentially from the definitions, and you shouldn't need to use finite-dimensionality.  The other direction will be harder.  (It also doesn't need finite-dimensionality, but it is probably easier to prove in the finite-dimensional setting.)  Regards,

Comment: And once you've proved $T$ is surjective iff $T^*$ is injective, the other one follows immediately since the canonical isomorphisms from $V \to (V^*)^*$ and $W \to (W^*)^*$ take $T$ to $(T^*)^*$.

Comment: @treble I suspect a basis proof might work.

Comment: @ronno See my answer, what do you think?

Comment: @treble What do you think of my answer?

Answer (score 1):

So, I see now that if $f \in W^*$ and $T^*(f) = 0=f\circ T$, then because $T$ is surjective,
we have for $w\in W$ there exists $v\in V$ such that $Tv=w$. Thus, $(f \circ T)(v) = f(T(v)) = f(w)=0$, so for all $w\in W$ we have that $f(w)=0$, so that $f=0$. Hence, it follows that $T^*$ is injective, right?

Comment: Dear Barisa, This is correct.  Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

For the second part I see now that for $g \in V^*$ and $f \in W^*$ we must have $T^*(f) = g$. Let $v_1,\dots,v_n$ be a basis of $V$; then the list $Tv_1,\dots,Tv_n$ is linearly independent in $W$, so we can extend it to a basis $Tv_1,\dots,Tv_n,w_1,\dots,w_k$ of $W$. Now we can define $f : W \rightarrow F$ by setting $f(Tv_i) = g(v_i)$ and $f(w_i) = 0$. Then $T^*(f) : V \rightarrow F$ and $T^*(f)(v_i) = (f \circ T)(v_i) = f(Tv_i) = g(v_i)$, so $T^*(f) = g$, as desired.

Comment: I recommend this:  Bach, J.S.: Fantasia and Fugue, for organ in G minor ("Great"), BWV 542: Fugue

Comment: Dear Barisa, The body of the argument looks correct, but the first sentence is a bit strange: you are choosing $g$ and trying to construct $f$, but this is not what your first sentence says.  Regards,